# How to configure DirectKafkaInputDStream not to stop on deserializer exceptions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I create an `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream` as the [guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) tells me to, with a custom value deserializer:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> config.kafka,
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[MyValueDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "my-group",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array(config.topic)
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, MyValue](topics, kafkaParams)
)
```

In my custom deserializer I copied exception handling from `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer`:

```
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException(...);
        }
```

and when it actually throws a serialization exception, I see its stacktrace in driver logs, and the next line is

```
INFO StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
```

Running it on Spark 2.1.0 in with `spark-submit` in client mode.

So I have to swallow exceptions in deserializer implementations and just return `null`. Is there a way to configure `ConsumerStrategy` in such a way that deserializer exceptions are just logged, but don't stop Spark Streaming context?